# Deployement Error for iOS in VS Cordova

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova, application-loader

VS version - **2015 with Cordova update 3**

Mac OS - **10.10.4**

iOS  - **9.0**

When building in release mode for iOS we get following warnings. But release folder is created with ipa and plist.

[image]

So when uploading that ipa using application loader it gives following 2 errors.

[image]

Comment: Those two messages are warning, so they may be unrelated.  A few questions: 1. What version of Cordova are you using? 2. What version of Node.js is installed on your Mac? 3. Are you building for a device or the simulator?  You must build for a device to use application loader.

Comment: I also noticed someone created this plugin which sounds like it mitigates the problem you mention.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057919/errors-in-cordovaxcode-ios-build):

There appears to be an issue with Cordova's iOS implementation when publishing apps created specifically using Xcode 7.

A Cordova community member has published a "cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking" plugin with a fix.

http://npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking

Install this plugin and you should be all set. A future Cordova version will resolve the problem fully.

Failing that, if you are using remotebuild you can also find the native project under ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds and make the modifications as described in the  [Cordova bug on the issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9161).

**EDIT:**

To resolve ITMS-90339, there is a second step you can do to patch in the near term. Grab the [build.xcconfig from the 3.9.x branch of the cordova-ios repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cordova-ios/3.9.x/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build.xcconfig) and place this under res/native/ios/cordova

Now **remove** this line:

```
CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist
```

Note that you will want to remove this custom build.xcconfig file if you upgrade to the version with the full patch that is forthcoming.

Comment: yeah I also found this custom plugin and it worked. but the first error is still coming. it is because apple have changed the code signing procedure since XCode 7. I wonder is there any fix for that.

Comment: Are you deploying to a device?  Does the project work in the iOS Simulator?  What is present in the output Window?  Often this provides more information about what is happening exactly.

Comment: I used remote iOS device option in release build mode. I finally copied the xcode project inside cordova folder in windows and ran with xcode in mac. finally using xcode I was able to submit to iTunes.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, which error is still occurring?  The deployment error, the --resource-rules warning, or the ITMS-90475 error?  The issue has been fixed in the Cordova code base and I expect there will be a release before too long with the fix in it but I want to validate that will fully resolve your issue.

Comment: @ChuckLantz I'm having the same issue. Yes adding the plugin solves ITMS-90475, but ITMS-90339 is still present. So you are saying that we need to wait for a new Cordova release?

Comment: Added same comment I mentioned in the other thread.  This is a second problem.

Comment: @ChuckLantz perfect. Now all the issues are gone.