# Errors in cordova+xcode ios build

Tags: xcode, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, application-loader

I am getting the following errors in Application Loader when trying to deliver my app(built in vs2015+cordova+remote xcode 7):

[image: Application Loader errors]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deployement Error for iOS in VS Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034658/deployement-error-for-ios-in-vs-cordova)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with Cordova's iOS implementation when publishing apps created specifically using Xcode 7.

A Cordova community member has published a "cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking" plugin with a fix.

http://npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking

Install this plugin and you should be all set. A future Cordova version will resolve the problem fully.

Failing that, if you are using remotebuild you can also find the native project under ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds and make the modifications as described in the [Cordova bug on the issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9161).

**EDIT:**

To resolve ITMS-90339, there is a second step you can do to patch in the near term. Grab the [build.xcconfig from the 3.9.x branch of the cordova-ios repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cordova-ios/3.9.x/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build.xcconfig) and place this under res/native/ios/cordova

Now **remove** this line:

```
CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist
```

Note that you will want to remove this custom build.xcconfig file if you upgrade to the version with the full patch that is forthcoming.

Comment: @dorad I'm having the same issue. This solves the two first errors, but I'm still getting ITMS-90339...

Comment: That is a second unrelated issue.  I'll add in how to fix that error above.

Comment: Thanks you both!
Just tried and the 90474, 90475 was gone.Unfortunately, 90339 is still there.

Comment: Update: 90339 solved with your solution(i also followed:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32762413/1157173 Section 2)

Answer (score 1):

By default Cordova doesn't fulfill all of the requirements for multitasking support. ([CB-9161](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9161)) You can follow the steps on that issue to make changes directly to the iOS project for multitasking support.

> 1. Use Xcode 7 (Cordova always uses the current SDK)
> 2. Click your Project icon in the Project Navigator
> 3. Click on your Target
> 4. Select the "General" tab
> 5. Go to the "Deployment Info" section
> 6. Select the "iPad" button segment
> 7. For "Device Orientation", select all four checkboxes (Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left, Landscape Right)
> 8. Add a new File: Launch Screen --> "Launch Screen.storyboard"
> 9. Click your Project icon in the Project Navigator
> 10. Click on your Target
> 11. Select the "General" tab
> 12. Go to the "App Icons and Launch Images" section
> 13. Select "Launch Screen.storyboard" from the "Launch Screen File" dropdown

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I don't have any Xcode project because i use the "remote" option in visual studio... what should i do?

Comment: Are you able to install Xcode on the remote mac? I don't believe you'll be able to do this through cordova configuration

Comment: I do have xcode on the remote mac, that's is how things are being compiled. but i don't have an xcode project. VS is doing all the job...

Comment: The xcode project is created automatically. If you copy your code onto the Mac and run `cordova prepare ios` it will be created. Unless you want to disable multitasking you'll have to apply manual changes to the project

Comment: which code to copy? the entire VS project and install VS on mac? every time i want to build? it's probably created automatically but doesn't remain in any folder after build.

Comment: Copy whichever folder has your config.xml in it. You don't need visual studio on the mac. Even when using visual studio's cordova tools, it's just a regular cordova project