# How to enable multitasking on iOS with Ionic / Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, multitasking

I've been trying to enable multitasking on my Ionic / Cordova app on iOS without success.

I've followed the steps in [[CB-9161] Support iPad multitasking in iOS 9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9161):

> The three rules are:
>
> 1. Build your apps with the iOS 9 SDK
> 2. Support all orientations
> 3. Use Launch Storyboards
>
> Fix for (1) is:
>
> 1. Use Xcode 7 (Cordova always uses the current SDK)
>
> Fix for (2) is:
>
> 1. Click your Project icon in the Project Navigator
> 2. Click on your Target
> 3. Select the "General" tab
> 4. Go to the "Deployment Info" section
> 5. Select the "iPad" button segment
> 6. For "Device Orientation", select all four checkboxes (Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left, Landscape Right)
>
> Fix for (3) is:
>
> 1. Add a new File: Launch Screen --> "Launch Screen.storyboard"
> 2. Click your Project icon in the Project Navigator
> 3. Click on your Target
> 4. Select the "General" tab
> 5. Go to the "App Icons and Launch Images" section
> 6. Select "Launch Screen.storyboard" from the "Launch Screen File" dropdown

I can see the new launch screen appearing before my app opens, but then I still can't split the view.

For your information, I'm building on a Mac with Xcode 8.2.1.
All `Device Orientation` boxes are ticked, and the `Requires full screen` is blank.

Any idea or direction to give me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem: I was using the [cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking) plugin to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034658/deployement-error-for-ios-in-vs-cordova). It turns out that this plugin was preventing multitasking (by forcing the "Requires Full Screen" option I believe). Removing the plugin solved the problem.